# PHP - Private variable accessible through Class

Tags: php, class, private-members

I am working on a PHP class which looks like this:

```
<?php
    class xyz{
           public $car1;
           public $car2;
           private $owner;

            public function __construct ($type){
              $this->car1 = $type;
              $this->owner = "John";
              return $this->owner();
          }
            private function owner(){
             return "Owner of ".$this->car1." is ".$this->owner;
          }
```

Now, here's the problem when I call this class via other code, I can easily access private variable and the return function is not working correctly.

Here's the sample:

```
  <?php
    $car = new xyz("Sedan");
    echo $car; //Expected result: Owner of Sedan is John.
   ?>
```

If I print $car, Here's what I get

```
 Object ( [car1] => Sedan [car2] => "" [owner:xyz:private] => John )
```

How can I achieve my desired results and How can I protect private variable?

All the helps and suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't return from a constructor.  Just echo `$car->owner()` or possibly use `__toString()`

Comment: You cannot echo a Class, you should have a function inside of it.

Comment: @Phiter you can echo a class, but you need `__toString` magic method defined.

Comment: Oh that's good to know, thank you!

Comment: `protect private variable` from __what__?

Comment: Implement `__toString()` method in your `xyz` class and from that method `return $this->owner();` So, `echo $car;` will give you the expected result.

Comment: @u_mulder I don't want to return its value publicly. I thought private variables can be used to store sensitive data.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Thanks. I have implemented __toString().

Answer (score 3):

1. Constructors are not supposed to return any value. The class constructor is supposed to initialize an object when creating a new instance (e.g. when you write `$car = new xyz("sedan");`, so anything you return goes nowhere. Create other methods in the class to return values.
2. If you want to echo the owner, make the `owner` method public and do `echo $car->owner();". The method returns a string, and then the string is echoed. Simple.
3. Echoing the object directly should result in an error in php 7, maybe you are running an older version of php that returns what you've seen, which is what happens if you call `var_dump($car);`. If you want to control how an object is converted into a string, you need to override the `__toString` method (see the [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring)).
4. Properties and methods visibility keywords are working fine, if you try to use `$car->owner` or `$car->owner()` without changing visibility you should see errors.

Comment: @ 3, I'm using print_r, not echo. But __toString works!

Comment: Any suggestions how to protect private data from getting access outside the  class?

Comment: Private data __is not__ getting accessed outside class, it's OOP basics.